# Can anyone explain how uksort() in PHP works?

Tags: php

I have read about `uksort` in the PHP manual but it is very difficult to understand.

Can any one help me out?

Here is an example:

```
 <?php  
 function my_sort($x, $y)  
 {  
   if ($x == $y) return 0;  
   return ($x > $y) ? -1 : 1;  
 }  
 $people = array(
   "10" => "javascript",  
   "20" => "php", "60" => "vbscript",  
   "40" => "jsp");  
 uksort($people, "my_sort");  
 print_r($people);  
 ?>
```

What is happening here?

Comment: uksort only returns either true or false so -1 should b 0 and what is your required output and what is getting produced wrong

Comment: Mian_Khurram_Iljaz, you are wrong. The manual clearly states that the comparison function should return a positive or negative number (to differentiate between which of the keys should go first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the [manual](http://php.net/uksort), your function (`my_sort` in this case) should return:

- a negative integer (in this case `-1`) if you consider `$a` to be less than `$b`
- a positive integer if you consider `$a` to be greater than `$b`
- `0` if you consider them to be the same.

As you may have guessed, `uksort` will use your comparison function to see in which order the elements should be in the sorted array. It will call your function multiple times, every time with two keys. You compare those to keys to each other and give your result back.

The idea is that you can program your own comparison function which does something non-trivial, for example if you want a certain key to always be first. Your trivial example can use the regular [krsort](http://php.net/krsort) instead.